# How to benefit from playing a racquet game with a player on a much lower level?

Tags: tennis, table-tennis, squash

Suppose you're teaching a beginner how to play (let's concentrate on various racquet games for that matter).

Do you have some tips on how the more experienced player can also benefit on some level from such games? A squash player once told me that one idea is to play with one's non-dominant hand, although I'm not sure what benefit would one get from that, (except perhaps in tennis, for the two-handed backhand), apart from the challenge/developing general dexterity (which I do find fun, but wondering whether there's more to that).

Are there any additional tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer addresses tennis.

Perhaps the most important advice is mental. If you want to improve, do not have an arrogant or superior mindset on court. Focus on improving yourself.

If your partner is not able to consistently return your balls, you are essentially limited to polishing your own footwork, technique, accuracy, and feel.

Otherwise, there are many additional things you can practice - depending on your own level. For low-level players, I suggest focusing on technique, footwork, and accuracy. For mid-level players, force yourself to work on the strokes you're less comfortable with e.g volleys, slices etc. Eliminating gaping weaknesses is the main obstacle to becoming a high(er)-level player. When you feel more-or-less comfortable everywhere in the court, work more on your feel.

If you are a high-level player you will find it surprisingly difficult to play normally against much weaker opponents, since you'll have far less pace to work with. Given that you will have ample time to think on court, I suggest thinking about the mechanics of your strokes. From my experience, this is very helpful in quickly making the necessary adjustments against different players e.g lefties, big hitters, pace changers etc. Apart from this, you should know what it is you need to be working on.

Answer (score 0):

The more experienced player could benefit in this scenario by seeing if the less experienced player is open to suggestions on how to improve. The process of passing along knowledge this way helps the experienced player to mature, because knowing something and being able to impart it are two different things.

[Further reading](http://www.ache.org/newclub/CAREER/MentorArticles/Benefits.cfm)